change screen mode automatically in flutter
i wan to change my layout from landscape to portrait and vice versa inside my app (depending on the rotation of the device by the user) in flutter
i tried using OrientationBuilder and MediaQuery but all of them read only for first time (even when user change the orientation mode) it doesn't detect the changes.
even i tried the WidgetsBindingObserver by adding:
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}

@override
void dispose() {
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
super.dispose();
}

and use didChangeMetrics() but same issue:
      @override
      void didChangeMetrics() {
        final orientation =
            WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.aspectRatio > 1
                ? Orientation.landscape
                : Orientation.portrait;

    _currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    print('Before Orientation Change: $_currentOrientation');
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      setState(() {
        _currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
      });
  print('After Orientation Change: $_currentOrientation');
});
}

i even tries to add setPrefrences inside the didChangeMetrics but didn't work either!

What was the thing that didn't work? When changing the orientation, are build and didChangeDependencies getting called in the widget?!

yes it enter for first time but when changing the orientation, it doesn't reach (doesn't print that it is now landscape for example)

Try this, I hope it will works
Orientation _orientation = Orientation.portrait;
      @override
      void didChangeMetrics() {
        final newOrientation = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.aspectRatio > 1
            ? Orientation.landscape
            : Orientation.portrait;
    
        if (newOrientation != _orientation) {
          setState(() {
            _orientation = newOrientation;
          });
        }
      }


still not working
